# Feature selection using BORUTA package

Tags: r, feature-selection

I am using Boruta package to perform feature selection on a data (33 attributes, 168 000 rows).
The feature selection is performed on balanced train data set. 
The result show that all attributes are important. 
However, when the sample size decreased to 70000, 35000, 7000, 3500, to 1000. Each data set leads to different results. The number of important attribute decreased. 
Could some one tell me why it happened?

Thank you very much
M